# How can I get Rails to connect to a SQL Server database with a period in it's name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, database-design

I have to connect to a SQL Server database that I do not control. The name is something like "foo.bar-baz.aaa". I've configured the name in `config/database.yml` with `database: foo.bar-baz.aaa`. When I attempt to query any model in that database, rails complains that "Database 'foo' does not exist".

I'm figuring that somewhere in the query builder, that period between "foo", and "bar-baz" is causing some mayhem. Is there any way that I can work around this?

Comment: Try delimit identifying the name: `[123.456-789.000]`. Though I do suggest that a better name is chosen to one that doesn't need to be delimit identified; object names cannot start with numbers, cannot contain periods, nor contain hyphens unless delimit identified.

Comment: What happens when you force the entity into a string?

`database: '123.456-789.000'`

Comment: > What happens when you force the entity into a string?


I get the same error.


> object names cannot start with numbers, cannot contain periods, nor contain hyphens unless delimit identified

I didn't know that - like I said, I do not control the DB. I'll try wrapping it in square brackets like you suggest, @Larnu. I think I saw that in my research before posting.

Comment: It turns out that doing *both* things works. My databse.yml file now has this: `database: '[123.456-789.000]'`

Comment: I think my example is bad, and may cause some confusion. I'll update it, and post an answer. Thank you both for pointing me in the right direction(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turns out to be quoting the DB name, while also "delimit identifying" the name (as per [Larnu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72379574/how-can-i-get-rails-to-connect-to-a-sql-server-database-with-a-period-in-its-na?noredirect=1#comment127865691_72379574)).

Now, my `config/database.yml` file has this configuration:

```
database: '[foo.bar-baz.aaa]'
```

Thanks to both [BenFenner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72379574/how-can-i-get-rails-to-connect-to-a-sql-server-database-with-a-period-in-its-na?noredirect=1#comment127865871_72379574), and [Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72379574/how-can-i-get-rails-to-connect-to-a-sql-server-database-with-a-period-in-its-na?noredirect=1#comment127865691_72379574) for pointing me in the right direction.